# Facebook does not show thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook's Graph API and I am trying to share a link to a page with a embedded swf video using the following CURL request.

```
curl -i -X POST \
-d "height=405" \
-d "link=https%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1SptrHN" \
-d "message=Test" \
-d "name=The%20Last%20Witch%20Hunter" \
-d "picture=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic1.webvideocore.net%2Fi%2Fstores%2F2%2Fitems%2Fbg%2F9%2F9c%2F9ce4632ed7b89b5a36638cdd6392914d.jpg" \
-d "source=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.streamingvideoprovider.com%2Fplayer3.swf%3Fclip_id%3Dar7hgx038sw8%26autoStart%3D1%26native_fs%3D1%26noControls%3D%26repeatVideo%3D%26stretch_video%3D%26brandNW%3D1%26start_img%3D1%26start_volume%3D100%26autoHide%3D1%26skinAlpha%3D80%26colorBase%3D%2523202020%26colorIcon%3D%2523FFFFFF%26colorHighlight%3D%2523fcad37%26viewers_limit%3D0%26cc_position%3Dbottom%26cc_positionOffset%3D70%26cc_multiplier%3D0.03%26cc_textColor%3D%2523ffffff%26cc_textOutlineColor%3D%2523000000%26cc_bkgColor%3D%2523000000%26cc_bkgAlpha%3D0.7" \
-d "type=link" \
-d "width=720" \
-d "access_token=CAAEl5c0JLDABAJpu3DJVbndfcmZCrr9xnk5zoWn5Ik9KEwS14autS1ZAc4ceDdzr4eTIqqzH6z8ePvkZA1gOVUZCKrInECJiFaZCgM1Y0JDocgfyyg9BLSpNzLtMZCOhiPpRPkk0URyCRDedQxQEx3yodXKiyzRJq7RKPZAVKrb77mlxA8fuUvRDZCcGgwgdZAuNZCWnLvtDly8wZDZD" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/feed"
```

As you can see I am setting the `picture` and the image is publicly available. However the Graph API Explorer returns the following url for the thumbnail which points to the `swf`.

`https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCRoO4J0CcrVO2M&w=130&h=130&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.streamingvideoprovider.com%2Fplayer3.swf%3Fclip_id%3Dar7hgx038sw8%26autoStart%3D1%26native_fs%3D1%26noControls%26repeatVideo%26stretch_video%26brandNW%3D1%26start_img%3D1%26start_volume%3D100%26autoHide%3D1%26skinAlpha%3D80%26colorBase%3D%2523202020%26colorIcon%3D%2523FFFFFF%26colorHighlight%3D%2523fcad37%26viewers_limit%3D0%26cc_position%3Dbottom%26cc_positionOffset%3D70%26cc_multiplier%3D0.03%26cc_textColor%3D%2523ffffff%26cc_textOutlineColor%3D%2523000000%26cc_bkgColor%3D%2523000000%26cc_bkgAlpha%3D0.7&cfs=1`

Furthermore sharing the link from the page manually shows the correct thumbnail.

What could be the reason for the wrong thumbnail?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed#publish lists the valid parameters for creating posts via that endpoint. It doesn’t mention `source` at all.

Comment: Actually there is - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0#params
Ant this is how you embed inline video in Facebook.

Comment: That is for the Feed _dialog_ – which is a completely different thing than making a post via API.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the `source` parameter really solved the issue. Can you put your comment as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed#publish lists the valid parameters for creating posts via that endpoint. It doesn’t mention `source` at all.

Although it seems to be a valid parameter for the Feed dialog – you are making a post made via API, and that’s something different.

If you want to share a link with a video, then I’d recommend embedding the video via the Open Graph meta tags – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video